# Getting name of button in function

Tags: javascript, unityscript, unity-game-engine

So I have a group of buttons that have the same function **in Unity**. I need the function to find the name of the button being pressed and react accordingly. How do you get the name of the button pressed? Please answer **in JS**

```
function Homes() {
if (button.name == "Cardboard Box" && money > 10) {
    Debug.Log("Removing " + house + " adding" + button.name);
    money -= 10;
    house = "Cardboard";
}else if (button.name == "Wood Shack" && money > 200) {
    money -= 200;
    house = "Wood Shack";
}
```

Comment: What is `button` in this context, it's not defined anywhere? Generally you don't have spaces in names.

Comment: button is the UI button that is using this function and in this script I named one Cardboard Box and Wood Shack

Comment: And did you try that without the spaces in the name attribute

Comment: without a space where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I was looking for 2 years ago was to have a parameter that gets the name of the button and uses it for something. Like the code below!

```
public void Level_Load (UnityEngine.UI.Button button) {
    Debug.Log(button.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the name of the button inside the hierarchy then use: `gameObject.name`. If you wish to get the text of the button, use `GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text` and make sure to add `using UnityEngine.UI;`.

Comment: The script is attached to another GameObject. That wont work.